# in react why we can access the "event" without passing it as an argument?

Tags: reactjs, function, events, parameters

**version 1**

```
**inside some component**
    
//define a function with "event" parameter
inputHandler=(event)=>{console.log(event.target.value)}
  
//invoke the function without the required argument  
render(){
  <input onChange={this.inputHandler} />
}
```

**version 2**

```
**inside some component**
    
//define a function with "event" parameter
inputHandler=(event)=>{console.log(event.target.value)}
    
//invoke the function with the required argument
render(){
  <input onChange={(e)=>this.inputHandler(e)} />
}
```

Both of the version would work in my point of view, but I don't understand that why the 1st version doesn't report an error for I don't pass any argument to it, since in the definition of the function, it requires "event" as an argument when being invoked

Comment: You are passing a function, the *caller* supplies the parameters.

Comment: `onChange={this.inputHandler}` - this is not a function call. You're only passing a function *reference*. `input` is responsible for actually calling the function and passing the required parameters.